# Target samelevel and parent lis

Tags: css, list, menu, parent, siblings

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4EbLu/

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Great Britain</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Germany</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="">France</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Paris</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Notre Dame</a></li>
          <li class="selected"><a href="">Parc des Princes</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sacre Coeur</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Rouen</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Lyon</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Marseilles</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Sweden</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Poland</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.selected > :first-child {
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #999; 
}
```

This will style the a tag "Parc des Princes" red with a grey background.

Is there a way with css to target all a tags on the same level as the a tag inside the .selected li and the a tags in the parent levels? In other words I want to make every a tag relating to france and the a tag with france itself to have color: #f00;

The html must be kept intact cause I cant change it and it must be done with css only.

Cheers / Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to access the parent selector, which cannot be done using css alone, which you can read up on more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), however there are some other selectors which you can find handy : [siblings,universal,etc](http://designshack.net/articles/css/css-selectors-just-the-tricky-bits/)

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot select parents with css. There is a [W3C Working Draft 2 May 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) but this is not supported by all browsers.